# PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT column reference is ambiguous, but how to specify table column?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

A section of a PL/pgSQL function looks like this:

```
    INSERT INTO assistant.accesstoken
    (
        submission_id,
        token,
        expires
    )
    VALUES
    (
        v_submission_id,
        assistant.pseudo_encrypt(v_submission_id),
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + v_token_duration
    )
    ON CONFLICT (submission_id)
    DO UPDATE SET
        expires = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + v_token_duration
    RETURNING token
    INTO v_accesstoken;
```

...and gives me a complaint:

```
psycopg.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "submission_id" is ambiguous
LINE 13:     ON CONFLICT (submission_id)
                         ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO assistant.accesstoken
    (
        submission_id,
        token,
        expires
    )
    VALUES
    (
        v_submission_id,
        assistant.pseudo_encrypt(v_submission_id),
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + v_token_duration
    )
    ON CONFLICT (submission_id)
    DO UPDATE SET
        expires = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + v_token_duration
    RETURNING token
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function assistant.evaluation_begin(character varying,character varying) line 115 at SQL statement
```

**There is no variable named `submission_id`.** Name only exists as a column name.

Unfortunately, it seems to be an error to specify table for the `submission_id`:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 140:     ON CONFLICT (accesstoken.submission_id)
```

**How do I fix this then?** How to prefix *conflict_target* for `ON CONFLICT` in a way that it is accepted?

Additional, can someone point me to a source where I could learn how variables and `ON CONFLICT` can go together? How would an `INSERT` be interested on a "conflict" in a PL/pgSQL variable when inserting a row, and what would it even mean? I am genuinely curious...

*Does PostgreSQL have overzealous checking or something? There are no variables, anywhere ever in this application, that would not be prefixed with  `in_`, `out_`, `inout_`, `r_` or `v_`, ...meaning that there is no ambiguity of this kind that I could see.*

Comment: The question cannot be answered without the entire function code. The definition of the `assistant.accesstoken` table may also be necessary.

Comment: The question is incomplete without declaring your version of Postgres (`SELECT version()`), and your complete function definition, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was closed during the night, so I won't bother with this topic much more than just try to write this open a little better:

In the comments, klin provided a link [37.5.9. SQL Functions Returning TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE) which explains **why** this happened, however the question remains unanswered: **How does one prefix the `conflict_target` to tell PostgreSQL that it is a column, not a variable?**

*Furthermore, the linked "duplicate question" does not deal with the above. I thought this site wanted to accumulate knowledge and information - now this hasty and incorrect closure makes it seem like a support ticket handling (workaround found, close it). Well, if this is what you want of this site, then that's what you do.*

**Description of the issue.** Because returning a `TABLE` is equivalent of returning a `SETOF`, the "column" names are then just variable names in the local scope, it seems (as opposed to be in a namespace of the anonymous table). Thus, the definition of the return `TABLE` which had `submission_id` (as shown below) was the cause of the ambiguity and renaming that, UPSERT's `ON CONFLICT` column / conflict_target is no longer ambiguous. *(May have felt like a bug, but its not...)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
assistant.evaluation_begin(
    in_course_id        VARCHAR,
    in_uid              VARCHAR
)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        submission_id   INTEGER,
        accesstoken     INTEGER
    )
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    SECURITY DEFINER
    VOLATILE
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
AS $$
```

This information hopefully allows others to see this condition (should they experience a similar issue) and this will certainly help working around it, even if doesn't provide the syntax/tools to maintain the call interface intact.

The second question also remains unanswered: In what way can a variable be a valid `ON CONFLICT` target and what does it even mean? It could be that such a thing doesn't even exist, and might just be because the same error string is used in all ambiguity cases. I personally suspect that this is the case.

But as this is closed now, we'll leave it at "problem solved, workaround found" state. Thank You for klin - the link was very helpful!

Comment: `RETURNS TABLE(columns)` is equivalent to using one or more `OUT` parameters. Are you aware that the names of parameters are visible in a function body?  [SQL Functions Returning TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)

Comment: Nope, that has never come up until now (weirdly enough). Thank's! (still leaves open why PostgreSQL would even consider that a variable is somehow valid for ON CONFLICT target ...or how does one specify then that it's a table column)

Comment: This is specific to SQL. Functions in Postgres are more like prepared statements than regular functions in compiled languages. Analysis of queries at the parsing stage would be too costly as it would have to relate to the structures of database objects. The problem is somehow similar to scripting languages where type errors are caught during execution.

Comment: I agree with you that some things are left unanswered and closed too quickly! One of the people who voted to close actually has had experience with a [more helpful workaround and explanation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105902/24311)! I found your question that was worded particularly well, so I don't know why they wouldn't want the traffic. But the basic answer from that post is to add a directive inside the `$$` and before `BEGIN` of your plpgsql: `#variable_conflict use_column` will make pg use the table when it could be confused, vs the default of throwing an error.